# Realm SyncConfiguration

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to synchronize a Realm database on my Android phone and a local Realm Objectserver similar to the RealmsTasks example in the documentation. I am using this code:

```
String authURL = "http://localhost:9080/auth";
SyncCredentials myCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(
        "...", "...", false); //user is in Realm database

SyncUser.loginAsync(myCredentials, authURL, this);
Log.i("TINGLE","credentials checked");

SyncConfiguration defaultConfig = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(
      currentUser(), 
      "http://localhost:9080/~/realmtingle").build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(defaultConfig);
```

However, the call to SyncConfiguration.Builder gives an exception. The error might be the path "http://localhost:9080/~/realmtingle", but has not been able to find guidelines on what the path should be in the Realm documentation.

The exception is:
....

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid scheme: http
 at io.realm.SyncConfiguration$Builder.validateAndSet(SyncConfiguration.java:320)
 at io.realm.SyncConfiguration$Builder.<init>(SyncConfiguration.java:293)
 at io.realm.SyncConfiguration$Builder.<init>(SyncConfiguration.java:280)
 at dk.staunstrups.tingle.TingleActivity.setUpRealmSync(TingleActivity.java:74)
 at dk.staunstrups.tingle.TingleActivity.onCreate(TingleActivity.java:38)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Realm URL should use `realm:` or `realms:`. It is only authentication that uses `http`. Below should work:

```
String authURL = "http://localhost:9080/auth";
SyncCredentials myCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(
        "...", "...", false); //user is in Realm database

SyncUser.loginAsync(myCredentials, authURL, this);
Log.i("TINGLE","credentials checked");

SyncConfiguration defaultConfig = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(
      currentUser(), 
      "realm://localhost:9080/~/realmtingle").build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(defaultConfig);
```